# How to prove that probablity of '1' of a Boolean expression calculated form truth table is equal to computed using Boolean expression.

Tags: probability, logic, boolean-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be two Boolean variables. Consider the following Boolean expression
$C=AB$. The truth table for $C$ is given as:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |

If the Boolean variables $A$ and $B$ are sampled assuming independence from an exhaustive random experiment, it can be concluded from the above truth table that $P[A=1]=\frac{2}{4}=0.5$ and $P[B=1]=\frac{2}{4}=0.5$. For computing $P[C=1]$, there can be possibly two methods:

1. By observation of number of ones in above truth table for $C$, such that $P[C=1]=\frac{1}{4}=0.25$
2. By using the SOP Boolean expression of $C$ from truth table, such that $P[C=1]=P[A=1]*P[B=1]=0.5 *0.5=0.25$

My doubt is that do methods 1 and 2 always yield the same result, even if $P[A=1]\neq 0.5$ or $P[B=1]\neq 0.5$ ?

Any resource material for such analysis would also be helpful.

Regards.

Comment: That seems to be the case if $A$ and $B$ are independent, where the result would follow from $P(C=1)=P((A=1)\cap(B=1))$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the second method? Do you expect it to work for all boolean expressions (including $\lor$ and repeated variables)?

Comment: Yes. OR operation would imply adding probabilities. Both methods provide the same results no matter the Boolean expression used with the probability of inputs being 0.5 (which is verifiable). However, I am not able to understand why they provide equal results (how to prove this mathematically), and even so if the input probabilities are different than 0.5, would it be possible to verify the same.

Comment: Are you sure? If $C=A\lor B$, is $C$ true with probability $.5+.5=1$?

Comment: SOP expression for the same is $C=AB+\bar{A}B+A\bar{B}$. Then $P[C=1]=0.5*0.5+(1-0.5)*0.5+0.5*(1-0.5)=0.75$ which can also be computed by observing ones in truth table as $\frac{3}{4}$.

Comment: Ok, so you require the expression to be in a very specific form. Can you see how that's equivalent to counting rows in the truth table?

Comment: Yes, my doubt is if $P[A=1] \neq 0.5$ and $P[B=1] \neq 0.5$, will the SOP expression $C=AB+\bar{A}B+A\bar{B}$ still compute correct $P[C=1]$? How do I verify this with truth table in such case?

Comment: Your truth table method relies implicitly on the assumption that the probability of $A$ and $\overline A$ are the same, as are the probability of $B$ and $\overline B$. If you want a method that applies more generally, you would have to change that. For example, if you represent the options as a rectangle cut in vertical lengths in proportion to the probabilities of $A$ and $\overline A$, an similarly in horizontal lengths by the probabilities of $B$ and $\overline B$, then the areas of the subrectangles would be the probabilities of both sides being true.